# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty while it should not be nil or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having this issue where the 'new' and sometimes 'edit' actions of my controllers will throw:

`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

While I'm 100% certain that the first argument is not nil nor empty. To hone down on this I'll only ask about the 'new' action since the resource is simply set to `Resource.new`

permissions/new.haml

```
= form_for @permission do |f|
  = f.label :name, class: 'form-control-label'
  = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
```

permissions_controller.rb

```
class PermissionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @permission = Permission.new
  end

  def show
    @modules = Modules.all
  end

  def index
    // handling content with api calls instead
  end

  ...
end
```

I have had this issue for a long time but I never figured out to successfully reproduce it in my development environment, until now.

I can reproduce this issue by going to the 'show' action of the same controller, then going back to the 'index' action and then going to the 'new' action. At this point the 'new' page does not work anymore until I edit the controller file or restart the server.

After changing the controller (adding a space at the end) or restarting the server it suddenly works again.

This is not the only resource this happens to. Often other resources like User have the same issue. I've had multiple projects that had the same issue that somehow disappeared so I never bothered to investigate more on this.

Ruby version: 2.3.5p376

Rails version: 5.1.4

edit:

I have noticed that I can't reproduce it anymore if I comment out `Modules.all`.

modules is not a activerecord class, it is a helper class for me to read out the different files in my directories, might this reading out give problems?

modules.rb

```
class Modules
  def self.all
    controllers = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/**/*.rb").
      map{ |e|
        if e.include?('/api/')
          e.match(/api\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*.rb/)[0].gsub('.rb', '').gsub('/', '::_').camelcase
        else
          e.match(/[^\/]*.rb/)[0].gsub('.rb', '').camelcase
        end
      }
    modules = {}
    controllers.each do |e|
      c = Object.const_get e
      modules[e.gsub(':','').gsub('Controller', '').underscore] = get_actions_for c if
        !no_permission_needed_for e and c.action_methods.size > 0
    end

    return modules
  end

  def self.get_actions_for(controller)
    actions = controller.action_methods
    grouped_actions.each do |key, value|
      actions.delete(key)
    end

    return actions
  end

  def self.grouped_actions
    {"new" => "create", "edit" => "update"}
  end

end
```

edit:

What I have noticed is that I'm trying to call `actions.delete(key)` where actions is a `Set` of strings where `key` is a `String`

When I do `actions = controller.action_methods.to_a` and force the set to an array my issue seems to go away. At least I can't reproduce it anymore. Now I'm wondering if there is something fundamentally going wrong in ruby where deleting something from a `Set` does weird stuff under the hood.

Comment: I wonder why you submit your form to ```url: permissions_path```, ie by sending POST/PUT request to ```index``` method? Why not using standard ```create / update```?

Comment: Instead of ```permissionscontroller.rb``` you probably mean ```permissions_controller.rb``` ?

Comment: My bad, typo on my part, the file is named correctly as permissions_controller.rb. as of the extra url, you're right it is unnecessary, the form helper should handle it correctly on it's own

Comment: I just had an idea that in case of failed form validation you might call rendering ```new.haml``` template from ```index``` action, where ```@permission``` is not set

Comment: even if I set `@permission = Permission.new` in `index` the problem keeps occurring. So I'm guessing that's not the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out.

What I noticed is that in `modules.rb` I'm loading the actions inside a controller through `controller.action_methods`. after this I'm deleting the `new` and `edit` actions.

I was under the assumption that I was simply receiving a set of strings containing the action names instead of the actual actions. So it seems logical that if I delete the `new` and `edit` actions that my views would default to the `new` and `edit` actions in ActionController::Base. Which would mean that @permission is not set and the view throws a well deserved error.

I'm assuming that doing this removes these actions in runtime for the controller. which means that it would of course work again after I restart the server.

So I fixed my issue by doing `controller.action_methods.to_a` which forces decoupling of the actual actions in the controller. After this I'm free to delete strings in this array that I don't require.

Moral of the story: Watch out with `controller.action_methods`?

Answer (score 0):

One way that it would work but is **not recommended** would be to initialize a `Permission` instance inside the form:

```
<%= form_for Permission.new do |f| %>
```

Check if the view containing your form is actually being rendered by the `new` action of your `PermissionsController`.

Comment: I'm aware that it would work like that, but as you said it is not recommended and it also won't properly populate the fields again if the resource cannot be saved. Also I have updated my question, I'm fairly certain something weird is happening under the hood.

Comment: is the form being rendered by the `new` action of `PermissionsController`, can you confirm that?

Comment: Affirmative, the form is rendered by the `new` action. I have kinda solved my problem, but this leaves me with greater questions of why a `Set` works in weird ways towards the framework architecture